# Select random row for each unique value in one specific column od fata frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have quite simple request that I cannot, however, deal with by use of one code line.

All I want is to subset an input data frame in the way that in the output data frame there is only one **randomly** selected row for each unique value (factor's level) of one particular data frame's column.

E.x. I have (v2 is a *particular data frame's column*)

```
   v1 v2
1   A  1                      
2   B  1      
3   C  2
4   A  1
5   B  2
6   B  1
7   B  1
8   C  2
9   D  1
10  E  1
```

And want to have as an output data frame:

```
   v1 v2
1   B  1                      
2   C  2
```

Thank you for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *way* more than what you asked for, but I wrote a function called [`stratified`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112) that lets you take random samples from a `data.frame` by one or more group variables.

You can load it and use it like this:

```
library(devtools)
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112")
# [1] "https://raw.github.com/gist/6424112"
# SHA-1 hash of file is 0006d8548785ec8a5651c3dd599648cc88d153a4    

## One row
stratified(mydf, "v2", 1)
#    v1 v2
# 10  E  1
# 8   C  2

## Two rows
stratified(mydf, "v2", 2)
#   v1 v2
# 2  B  1
# 6  B  1
# 3  C  2
# 5  B  2
```

---

I'll add official documentation to the function at some point, but here's a summary to help you get the best use out of it:

The arguments to `stratified` are:

- `df`: The input `data.frame`
- `group`: A character vector of the column or columns that make up the "strata".
- `size`: The desired sample size.

  - If `size` is a value less than 1, a proportionate sample is taken from each stratum.
  - If `size` is a single integer of 1 or more, that number of samples is taken from each stratum.
  - If `size` is a vector of integers, the specified number of samples is taken for each stratum. It is recommended that you use a *named vector*. For example, if you have two strata, "A" and "B", and you wanted 5 samples from "A" and 10 from "B", you would enter `size = c(A = 5, B = 10)`.
- `select`: This allows you to subset the groups in the sampling process. This is a `list`. For instance, if your `group` variable was "Group", and it contained three strata, "A", "B", and "C", but you only wanted to sample from "A" and "C", you can use `select = list(Group = c("A", "C"))`.
- `replace`: For sampling with replacement.

Comment: +1 nice. Cool function! I think I spy a use for this in my work already. Thanks Ananda.

Comment: @SimonO101, thanks. Let me know if you find any bugs. I'm working on a few `data.frame` related functions that I'll package up at some point....

Comment: I will be sure to do so. Cheers.

Comment: I have just checked this out, I stay amazed!

Comment: Very nice function! Looking forward to your package. +1!

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the unique values in your column and find the row indices for each vlaue and select one row index at random using `sample`. Like this:

```
#  Set seed for reproducible results
set.seed(1)

#  Generate indices
ind <- sapply( unique( df$v2 ) , function(x) sample( which(df$v2==x) , 1 ) )

#  Subset data.frame
df[ ind , ]
#  v1 v2
#2  B  1
#5  B  2
```